# Is there any way to refactor this custom component to reduce code duplication?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, jsx

I have this wrapper component for the mui `Tooltip` component with the added functionality that it automatically closes the tooltip when the table around it is being scrolled. The code works well but I want to improve the code quality since there are a few duplicate lines. Also I believe there should be a way to find the reference to the table once and use it in all three function calls. Any help would be appreciated and I apologise for such a generic question. I don't know how to make it more specific.

```
import { TooltipProps } from '@mui/material';
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Tooltip } from '../tooltip/Tooltip';

interface TableTooltipProps extends TooltipProps {
  selector?: string;
}

export function TableTooltip({
  selector = '.MuiTableContainer-root',
  children,
  ...props
}: TableTooltipProps) {
  const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = useState(false);
  const [timeoutId, setTimeoutId] = useState<number>(null);
  const ref = useRef<any>();

  const handleScroll = () => {
    console.warn('scrolling');
    setIsScrolling(true);
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.closest(selector).removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
      console.warn('aborted');
    }
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    setTimeoutId(
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        setIsScrolling(false);
      }, 500),
    );
  };

  const attachToScrollEvent = () => {
    if (ref.current) {
      console.warn('added');
      const tableElement = ref.current.closest(selector);
      tableElement.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    }
  };

  const detachFromScrollEvent = () => {
    if (ref.current) {
      console.warn('removed');
      const tableElement = ref.current.closest(selector);
      tableElement.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    }
  };

  return !isScrolling ? (
    <>
      <Tooltip
        onOpenCallback={attachToScrollEvent}
        onCloseCallback={detachFromScrollEvent}
        {...props}
      >
        {children}
      </Tooltip>
      <td className="html-element-dummy" style={{ display: 'none' }} ref={ref} />
    </>
  ) : (
    <>{children}</>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz or Codesandbox? I can simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple refactor using `optional chaining` would allow you to reduce code by ignoring the error when the ref is initially undefined for an insignificant period of time, on the `.closest` and the `addEventListener` / `removeEventListener` calls.

```
import { TooltipProps } from '@mui/material';
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Tooltip } from '../tooltip/Tooltip';

interface TableTooltipProps extends TooltipProps {
  selector?: string;
}

export function TableTooltip({
  selector = '.MuiTableContainer-root',
  children,
  ...props
}: TableTooltipProps) {
  const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = useState(false);
  const [timeoutId, setTimeoutId] = useState<number>(null);
  const ref = useRef<any>();
  const tableElement = ref?.current?.closest(selector);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    setIsScrolling(true);
    tableElement?.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    setTimeoutId(window.setTimeout(() => setIsScrolling(false), 500));
  };

  const attachToScrollEvent = () => tableElement?.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  const detachFromScrollEvent = () => tableElement?.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

  return !isScrolling ? (
    <>
      <Tooltip
        onOpenCallback={attachToScrollEvent}
        onCloseCallback={detachFromScrollEvent}
        {...props}
      >
        {children}
      </Tooltip>
      <td className="html-element-dummy" style={{ display: 'none' }} ref={ref} />
    </>
  ) : (
    <>{children}</>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to improve my own code. The answer by @Wesley unfortunately had some undesirable side effects.

I am just not sure whether useCallback is necessary here.

```
import { TooltipProps } from '@mui/material';
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Tooltip } from '../tooltip/Tooltip';

interface TableTooltipProps extends TooltipProps {
  selector?: string;
}

export function TableTooltip({
  selector = '.MuiTableContainer-root',
  children,
  ...props
}: TableTooltipProps): JSX.Element {
  const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = useState<boolean>();
  const [timeoutId, setTimeoutId] = useState<number>();
  const [tableElement, setTableElement] = useState<Element>();
  const ref = useRef<HTMLTableCellElement>();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTableElement(ref.current?.closest(selector));
  }, [ref, selector]);

  const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
    tableElement.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    setIsScrolling(true);
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    setTimeoutId(
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        setIsScrolling(false);
      }, 500),
    );
  }, [tableElement, timeoutId]);

  const attachToScrollEvent = useCallback(() => {
    tableElement.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, [tableElement, handleScroll]);

  const detachFromScrollEvent = useCallback(() => {
    tableElement.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, [tableElement, handleScroll]);

  return !isScrolling ? (
    <>
      <Tooltip
        onOpenCallback={attachToScrollEvent}
        onCloseCallback={detachFromScrollEvent}
        {...props}
      >
        {children}
      </Tooltip>
      <td className="html-element-dummy" style={{ display: 'none' }} ref={ref} />
    </>
  ) : (
    <>{children}</>
  );
}
```